# How to set a value for a specific threshold in SVC model and generate a confusion matrix?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I need to set a value to a specific threshold and generate a confusion matrix. The data is in a csv file (11,1 MB), the link for download is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cQFp7HteaaL37CefsbMNuHqPzkINCVzs/view?usp=sharing?

First, I received an error message: ""AttributeError: predict_proba is not available when  probability=False""
So I used this for correction:

```
svc = SVC(C=1e9,gamma= 1e-07)
scv_calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(svc)
svc_model = scv_calibrated.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I've seen a lot on the internet and I didn't quite understand how a specific threshold value is being personanized. Sounds pretty hard.
Now, I see a wrong output:

```
array([[   0,    0],
       [5359,   65]])
```

I have no idea what is wrong.

I need help and I'm new in that.
Thanks

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('fraud_data.csv')

X = df.iloc[:,:-1]
y = df.iloc[:,-1]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)



def answer_four():
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

 
    svc = SVC(C=1e9,gamma= 1e-07)
    scv_calibrated = CalibratedClassifierCV(svc)
    svc_model = scv_calibrated.fit(X_train, y_train)
  
    # set threshold as -220
    y_pred = (svc_model.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] >= -220) 
   
    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_pred, svc_model.predict(X_test))
    
    return conf_matrix
answer_four()
```

This function should return a confusion matrix, a 2x2 numpy array with 4 integers.

Comment: Answer not helpful?

Comment: It helped me see one of the wrong parts of my code. One of my mistakes was using the confusion matrix incorrectly. thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code produces the expected output, in addition to the fact that in the previous code I was using the confusion matrix incorrectly I should have also used decision_function and getting the output filtering the 220 threshold.

```
def answer_four():
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
    from sklearn.svm import SVC
    from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    #SVC without mencions of kernel, the default is rbf
    svc = SVC(C=1e9, gamma=1e-07).fit(X_train, y_train)

    #decision_function scores: Predict confidence scores for samples
    y_score = svc.decision_function(X_test)

    #Set a threshold -220
    y_score = np.where(y_score > -220, 1, 0)
    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_score)

####threshold###
#input threshold in the model after trained this model
#threshold is a limiar of separation of class   

return conf_matrix

answer_four()
#output: 
array([[5320,   24],
       [  14,   66]])
```

Comment: Wish you had changed the parameters a little so that this code didn't contain the exact answer to one of the assignments in a Coursera course :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the confusion matrix in a wrong way.

The idea behind the confusion matrix is to have a picture as to how good our predictions `y_pred` are compared with the ground truth `y_true`, usually in a *test* set.

What you actually do here is computing a "confusion matrix" between your predictions with the custom threshold of -220 (`y_pred`), compared to some other predictions with the default threshold (the output of `svc_model.predict(X_test)`), which does not make any sense.

Your ground truth for the test set is `y_test`; so, to get the confusion matrix with the default threshold, you should use

```
confusion_matrix(y_test, svc_model.predict(X_test))
```

To get the confusion matrix with your custom threshold of -220, you should use

```
confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) for more details in the usage (which is your best friend, and should *always* be the first place to look at, when having issues or doubts).

Comment: Got it and thanks. In this case here I was actually using the confusion matrix the wrong way. But after I used it the right way I still got incorrect output:

array ([[0, 5344],
       [0.80]])

I realized that I had to make other corrections to my code using the decision function and filtering the threshold:
y_score = svc.decision_function (X_test)
    
#Set a threshold -220
y_score = np.where (y_score> -220,1,0)
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix (y_test, y_score)

Comment: It is still unclear why I have only the decision function seems to work in this case and provide the correct output. The decision function with which to trust the
classifier predicts the positive class. Predict would return the predicted classes, and predict_proba would return the probability of predicting classes ok?



Why do predict_proba not work here? Maybe I didn't really understand the concept. Here's my final, tuned code that produces the only output considered correct: